# New Button at Review Section

Tags: support, review

While reviewing a post, I noticed that "No Action Needed" button was added:

[image]

Will this button prevent a first post to appear as a late post?

Comment: Hi, can you give us a headsup on what button was added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158761/205469) on meta SO will explain the function of the added button. Here's a recap:

> We've now implemented this. Obviously, my initial optimism in assuming folks who didn't feel strongly about voting would do something else useful was completely misguided. I was wrong, and I apologize sincerely for not realizing this sooner.
>
> I'm quickly souring (again) on the idea of allowing voting in these
>   queues at all; not because of the people who vote without reviewing at
>   all, but because it's made it impractical to implement something
>   that's been a staple in other queues: multiple reviewers per review
>   item. Indeed, we badly need a locking mechanism to prevent multiple
>   reviewers (3-4 votes on new posts can really break things), however
>   implementing this will be tricky.
>
> So for now, we're adding a "No Action Needed" button. We'll be
>   watching to see if it is effective in siphoning off folks with no real
>   opinion on the posts they're reviewing.